# Wifi connected through router or extender

Tags: wireless-networking, powerline-networking

I just configured the TPlink powerline extender to have same SSID and password with my router’s.

Before that, normally i can still connect my cellphone in basement with the router, just that the signal sometimes drops.

How do i know if my cellphone now is surfing through the extender, or still through the router because the router’s signal is suddenly “strong”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience you can only see that on the web interface of the repeater or the router - if these have a web page showing which devices are connected over WiFi.